# How to create filters for QTableWidget in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to know how can i create filters for QTableWdget like in excel.

I posted a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068823/how-to-create-filters-for-qtable-in-pyqt) to create filters for QTableView like in excel. And its answered.

I tried the same way for QTableWidget and i am getting `TypeError: QTableWidget.setModel() is a private method`

So is there a way i can get filters for `QTableWidget`.