# PyQT5 and Filtering a Table using multiple columns

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to make a `PyQt5` GUI to show a Pandas dataframe in the form of a table and provide column filtering options, similar to the Microsoft Excel filters. So far I managed to adopt a similar [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068823/how-to-create-filters-for-qtableview-in-pyqt). Here is the picture of my table in the GUI:

[image]

As shown in the figure above, there are two ways to filter columns: the Regex Filter and clicking on each column. There is however a problem I need help to address: the currently applied filters (either regex filter or column click) disappear when I filter a second column. I want the second filter as `AND`, i.e. a filter that satisfies column 1 `AND` column 2.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import pandas as pd

class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df.copy()

    def toDataFrame(self):
        return self._df.copy()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                # return self.df.index.tolist()
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]))

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._df[col].dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
        self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()


class myWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralwidget  = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.lineEdit       = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.view           = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox       = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.label          = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("Regex Filter")

        self.load_sites()
        self.comboBox.addItems(["{0}".format(col) for col in self.model._df.columns])

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged)

        self.horizontalHeader = self.view.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)


    def load_sites(self):

        df = pd.DataFrame({'site_codes': ['01', '02', '03', '04'],
                           'status': ['open', 'open', 'open', 'closed'],
                           'Location': ['east', 'north', 'south', 'east'],
                           'data_quality': ['poor', 'moderate', 'high', 'high']})

        self.model = PandasModel(df)
        self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):

        self.logicalIndex   = logicalIndex
        self.menuValues     = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        self.signalMapper   = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(self.logicalIndex)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)

        valuesUnique = self.model._df.iloc[:, self.logicalIndex].unique()

        actionAll = QtWidgets.QAction("All", self)
        actionAll.triggered.connect(self.on_actionAll_triggered)
        self.menuValues.addAction(actionAll)
        self.menuValues.addSeparator()
        for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(list(set(valuesUnique)))):
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(actionName, self)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(action, actionNumber)
            action.triggered.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
            self.menuValues.addAction(action)
        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)
        headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())
        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(self.logicalIndex)

        self.menuValues.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(  "",
                                        QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                        QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                        )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
        stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(  stringAction,
                                        QtCore.Qt.CaseSensitive,
                                        QtCore.QRegExp.FixedString
                                        )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
        search = QtCore.QRegExp(    text,
                                    QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                    QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                    )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app  = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = myWindow()
    main.show()
    main.resize(800, 600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When 2 or more filters are applied, the operation is AND or OR?, that is, if filter F1 and filter F2 are applied, then only the rows that meet F1 AND F2 or that at least meet F1 OR F2 should be shown

Comment: The operation is AND. Good point, I should have cleared that.

Comment: Okay, I understand how popup works since the filter is applied to the column, but to which column does the QLineEdit text filter apply? And that filter also applies the AND function?

Comment: I'm planning to add a separate QLineEdit text filter for each column later on but for now please consider it for the first column. It is an AND function

Comment: @BehzadJamali so you want to apply *multiple* text filters, each one to a different column?

Comment: @musicamante Yes that is the aim eventually but I was gonna ask it as a separate question if I failed after trying it myself :)

Comment: @BehzadJamali Ok, keep in mind that to obtain that you'll probably need to subclass QSortFilterProxyModel, add a function to set the regex for the wanted column (after which [`invalidateFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#invalidateFilter) has to be call each time), and then reimplement [`filterAcceptsRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow), in which you'll need to manually check each column for its regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to implement a custom filtering process then you must override the filterAcceptsRow method, obtain the texts of each column and verify if they meet the condition, if they do return True, otherwise False. To recalculate the filter you must call the invalidateFilter method:

```py
class CustomProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._filters = dict()

    @property
    def filters(self):
        return self._filters

    def setFilter(self, expresion, column):
        if expresion:
            self.filters[column] = expresion
        elif column in self.filters:
            del self.filters[column]
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        for column, expresion in self.filters.items():
            text = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, column, source_parent).data()
            regex = QtCore.QRegExp(
                expresion, QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive, QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
            )
            if regex.indexIn(text) == -1:
                return False
        return True
```

```
class myWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...

    def load_sites(self):
        # ...

        self.model = PandasModel(df)
        self.proxy = CustomProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        print("finished loading sites")

    # ...

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        self.proxy.setFilter("", filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
        stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        self.proxy.setFilter(stringAction, filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
        self.proxy.setFilter(text, self.proxy.filterKeyColumn())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(index)
```

---

**Plus:**
If you want to change the font of the QHeaderView then you must return the font in the headerData as shown below:

```py
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df.copy()
        self.bolds = dict()

    def toDataFrame(self):
        return self._df.copy()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                try:
                    return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
                except (IndexError,):
                    return QtCore.QVariant()
            elif role == QtCore.Qt.FontRole:
                return self.bolds.get(section, QtCore.QVariant())
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                try:
                    # return self.df.index.tolist()
                    return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
                except (IndexError,):
                    return QtCore.QVariant()
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def setFont(self, section, font):
        self.bolds[section] = font
        self.headerDataChanged.emit(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 0, self.columnCount())
    # ...
```

```
class myWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
   @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        self.proxy.setFilter("", filterColumn)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.model.setFont(filterColumn, font)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
        stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        self.proxy.setFilter(stringAction, filterColumn)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        self.model.setFont(filterColumn, font)
```

Comment: This works thanks. Is it possible to mark/sign those columns that are filtered?

Comment: @BehzadJamali What do you mean, explain yourself better

Comment: For example, I want the column name that has been filtered to become bold.