# Highlighting the header of a filtered column in a QTableView - PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I implement a customProxyModel which filters a QTableView in my main dialog. The code is inspired from the following discussing [PyQT5 and Filtering a Table using multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407029/pyqt5-and-filtering-a-table-using-multiple-columns)

Here is how I defined my CustomProxyModel(). It keeps track of filtered columns in a list called `filtered_columns` and sets the header font of filtered columns to bold in the `headerData()` method.

```
class CustomProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._filters = dict()
        self.filtered_columns = list()

    @property
    def filters(self):
        return self._filters

    def setFilter(self, expresion, column):
        if expresion:
            self.filters[column] = expresion
            self.filtered_columns.append(column)
        elif column in self.filters:
            del self.filters[column]
            self.filtered_columns.remove(column)
        self.invalidateFilter()


    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        for column, expresion in self.filters.items():
            text = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, column, source_parent).data()
            text = str(text)
            regex = QtCore.QRegExp(
                expresion, QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive, QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
            )
            if regex.indexIn(text) == -1:
                return False
        return True

    
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        
        # Set font to bold
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.FontRole:
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            if section in self.filtered_columns:
                font.setBold(True)
            return font
        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)
```

Here is how I defined my tableView (Note: I implemented in PyQt UI)

```
class myTableViewDialog(QDialog, myTableView.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myTableViewDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.populatemyTableView()
    
    def populatemyTableView(self):
        # Set up the model
        self.model = QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable("MY_TABLE")
        self.model.select()
        
        # Customize the table view
        self.horizontalHeader = self.myTableView.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.setStyleSheet(
            "QHeaderView::section \
            {\
                background-color: #4C6199;\
                color: white; \
            }"
            )

        self.myTableView.verticalHeader().setStyleSheet(
            "QHeaderView::section \
            {\
                background-color: #4C6199;\
                color: white; \
            }"
            )

        # Make the table view read only
        self.myTableView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

        # Link the table view to the model
        self.myTableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.myTableView.resizeColumnsToContents()


        """
        Testing header filtering
        """

        # self.proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy_model = CustomProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.myTableView.setModel(self.proxy_model)
        self.horizontalHeader = self.myTableView.horizontalHeader()

        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)
       
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):
        self.logicalIndex = logicalIndex
        self.menuValues = QMenu(self)
        self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)  
        valuesUnique = [    self.model.index(row, self.logicalIndex).data()
                            for row in range(self.model.rowCount())
                            ]
        actionAll = QAction("All", self)
        actionAll.triggered.connect(self.on_actionAll_triggered)
        self.menuValues.addAction(actionAll)
        self.menuValues.addSeparator()
        for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(list(set(valuesUnique)))):              
            action = QAction(str(actionName), self)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(action, actionNumber)  
            action.triggered.connect(self.signalMapper.map)  
            self.menuValues.addAction(action)
        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)  
        headerPos = self.myTableView.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())        
        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionViewportPosition(self.logicalIndex)
        self.menuValues.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        self.proxy_model.setFilter("", filterColumn)
    

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
        stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        self.proxy_model.setFilter(stringAction, filterColumn)
```

My question: How can I modify the code so that instead of making the header text bold of a filtered column, I change the background colour of the header? Slight clarification: I do not want to modify the background color of the entire header so setting a StyleSheet is not appropriate in this case. What I want instead is modifying the background color only of the header of filtered columns.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that: 1. QSignalMapper is only maintained for historical reasons, and lambdas are normally more flexible. In a case such as yours, you don't even need those, as you can use `action.setData(actionNumber)` and only connect the `triggered` signal of the menu, then you get the number directly from the action argument of the called slot; 2. avoid slot decoration unless you really know what you're doing, as it's almost always unnecessary; 3. both the menu and the actions you're creating are persistent, possibly wasting memory unnecessarily: at least make the actions children of the menu »

Comment: » (`action = menu.addAction(actionName)`); then, since the menu is an instance attribute, it makes little sense to always recreate it, instead create it in the `__init__` and call `clear()` before repopulating it; alternatively, do *not* make it an instance attribute, but set the `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute; 4. `sorted()` accepts any iterable, no need to convert the set into a list; 5. `headerPos = self.horizontalHeader.mapToGlobal(QPoint())`, or, even better: `pos = QPoint(header.sectionViewportPosition(index), header.height()); menu.exec(header.mapToGlobal(pos))`.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for all the notes/feedback you provided - very helpful and made my code more optimised!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to set custom colors for the headers is to implement the related roles for the `headerData` function of the model.

This will always be ignored, though, if the header view is affected by stylesheets that set color properties.

While there are various possibilities (including overriding [`paintSection()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#paintSection) of a QHeaderView subclass), the simplest solution for such a case is to completely avoid style sheets for headers and implement `headerData()` on the proxy:

```py
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and section in self.filtered_columns:
                return QColor('red')
            return QColor('#4C6199')
        elif role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            return QColor(Qt.white)
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.FontRole:
            if section in self.filtered_columns:
                font = QFont()
                font.setBold(True)
                return font
        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)
```

Note that some styles (notably, the default used on Windows) completely disregard header colors coming from the model.

In such cases, the easiest work around is to set a more compliant style for the headers:

```py
self.horizontalHeader.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))
self.verticalHeader.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))
```

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense why the header column set in headerData was ignored given I'm operating on Windows OS. Your work aroud turned out to work perfectly!